# Get page_access_token

Tags: facebook-page

As I knew there is a way to get access token via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.

Is there other way to get page_access_token by API?

I want to post request to add app to facebook page but it require a page_access_token as below:

https://graph.facebook.com/myPageId/tabs/?app_id=myAppId&access_token=myPageAccessToken

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The current user must be an administrator of this page;

`extended permission needed - manage_pages`
refer url: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Try this:

```
$config = array(
'appId' => FB_APP_ID,
'secret' => FB_SECRET_KEY,
'cookie' => true // enable optional cookie support  
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

$params = array(
'scope' => 'manage_pages',
'redirect_uri' => FB_APP_URL,
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params); 

<script> window.top.location.href = '<?php echo $loginUrl ?>';  </script>
```